# MYSQL function select sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I already create a function called calculate_marks(user_id) and it run properly,
but when i put in the insert statement, it will keep running in mysql and no respond, anyone know what is the problem?

```
INSERT INTO `marks`
(`marks_user_id`, `marks_addtime`, `marks_amount`
) 
SELECT `user_id`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
    (SELECT calculate_marks(`user_id`))
FROM `user`
WHERE `user`.`user_status` = 'A';
```

It will return the result that i want if i run this

```
SELECT `user_id`, (SELECT calculate_marks(`user_id`))
FROM `user`
WHERE `user`.`user_status` = 'A';
```

Comment: This is correct syntax for an INSERT INTO operation INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3);  You are missing out the VALUES part

Comment: @pravinnavle you are wrong! OP is using `Insert.. Select` statement. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks for pointing out my mistake. Got to learn something new about MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying a correlated subquery, without proper aliasing. You dont need to use subquery to calculate marks. Try the following instead:

```
INSERT INTO `marks`
(`marks_user_id`, `marks_addtime`, `marks_amount`
) 
SELECT `user_id`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), calculate_marks(`user_id`) 
FROM `user`
WHERE `user`.`user_status` = 'A';
```